# Sharing a domain name with Shopify and HTML/CSS

Tags: asp.net, .net, dns, shopify

Am I able to host both a Shopify store and a .NET Application on the same domain name? I would like to use some more advanced pages and graphics in my store that I don't think shopify allows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're are free to use subdomains as you wish. So you could setup links to:

- https://mygroovystuff.myshop.com or
- https://wallawalla.myshop.com

With Shopify running your store as https://myshop.com

You can use an App Proxy to do front-end to your back-end securely too. That might be all you need. Check it out.